# How to edit and loop an Array Object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, react-data-table-component

In my React project, I'm trying to output a table (using `react-data-table-component`).

So here it is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";

class WrapperTableTile extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {data} = this.props;
    const key = this.props.data[0];
    const keys = Object.keys({...key});

    return (
      <div className="card p-4 mb-4">
        <DataTable
          title=""
          columns={keys}
          data={data}
          defaultSortField="title"
          pagination
          selectableRows
          className="table myDataTable"
          highlightOnHover={true}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

WrapperTableTile.defaultProps={
  data:{
    title:"",
    columns:[],
    rows:[]
  }
}

WrapperTableTile.propTypes={
  data:WrapperTableTileType
}

export default WrapperTableTile;
```

My `data` is a JSON Array with different Objects, and I use `Object.key` to get only keys of the first Object, to use them as names of columns in the table.

It doesn't work because `keys` output is an `Object` like:
`{'ID','NAME','AGE',...}` instead of `DataTable` needs an array to be used for `columns={keys}`, like:

```
{
  name: "ID",
  selector: "ID",
  sortable: true,
},
{
  name: "NAME",
  selector: "NAME",
  sortable: true,
},
{
  name: "AGE",
  selector: "AGE",
  sortable: true,
},
```

So at the end, in `React` I don't know how to do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  {
    name: keys[i],
    selector: keys[i],
    sortable: true,
  }
}
```

How could I edit my array to use it as value in my component?

Comment: `{'ID','NAME','AGE',...}` is not a JSON

Comment: @testing_22 `data` is a JSON, the output you're referring is this: `keys = Object.keys({...key});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
const tblKeys = keys.map((item) => (
  {
    name: item,
    selector: item,
    sortable: true,
  }
))
```

Then in my component: `columns={tblKeys}`

Answer (score 0):

const keys = ['ID','NAME','AGE'].map(key=>{
name: key,
selector: key,
sortable: true
});